# How to invoke a Spring's controller from html+angularjs page?

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, model-view-controller

I have 2 page one is .jsp and another is .html. Both have two text boxes and a button. On a button click i am calling a post method using angularjs. But when am working with .jsp page it is working fine but the same thing is not working with .html.

Here my Spring's controller -

```
@RequestMapping(value="/springAngularJS",method=RequestMethod.POST)
 public String addUser(@RequestBody User user)
   {
   System.out.println("Adding user dtl....");
   }
```

Here is my jsp page-

```
$http.post("springAngularJS",$scope.user).
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.person = data;
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      alert( "Exception details: " + JSON.stringify({data: data}));
  });
```

The code is same for my .html file as well. But the above is working but when I deal with .html it is not.
I will add my XML file details also-

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
<mvc:resources mapping="/views/**" location="/WEB-INF/views/" />
```

Consider me as a beginner,learning by my self..facing challenges. Anyone has any solution please answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your angular app (front end) and your Spring app (back end) don't have any knowledge about each other. They can communicate, though, provided everything is setup correctly. The first argument to $http.post() is a URL. However, you provided 'springAngularJS', which is only the end of the url you are trying to hit. So this needs to be fixed.

Your Spring app is likely being run on your localhost, on port 8000, for example. So your Spring app would be available at http://localhost:8000, in this example. Think of this as the base url for your Spring application. When you use the following annotation in Spring,  `@RequestMapping(value="/springAngularJS",method=RequestMethod.POST)`,  you are saying that whenever a POST request is made to your server at `http://locahost:8000/springAngularJS` with the correct body/payload, that method will be run. It basically adds the 'value' argument onto the base url that I previously mentioned.

So from your angular app, you need to be hitting `http://locahost:8000/springAngularJS`, not just `springAngularJS`.

In summary, change `$http.post("springAngularJS",$scope.user)` to `$http.post("http://locahost:8000/springAngularJS",$scope.user)` (depending on your server's actual url/port).

You can also use a relative url for $http.post, assuming your server and your ui are being served from the same url/port, in which case you could simply do `$http.post("/springAngularJS",$scope.user)`. Note the slash at the beginning of the (relative) url.